# DB and php select random and pass variable

Tags: database, function, variables, random, joomla

I've done a module for Joomla 3, it's work but some time no, these module extract, with a function, a random user on line from tab session, then pass the variable to another function, to retrieve the avatar, and id skipe, its work but seems he extract random also the avatar from the user on line, meanwhile I have seen this process can bind a lot of work the db is there a way to lighten, another person told me that there could be security issues, I think due to the fact that the id of skipe is clear!

```
<?php

class modUno
{

public static function due()
{

$db = JFactory::getDBO();   
$query = "SELECT userid AS memTotal FROM #__session ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;";      
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->query();
return $result->fetch_object()->memTotal;
$mysqli->kill($db);
}

public static function tre()
{

$risultato = modUno::due();

$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT avatar FROM #__comprofiler WHERE id = '{$risultato}'; ";
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadResult();
return $result; 
$mysqli->kill($db);
} 

public static function quattro()
{

$risultato = modUno::due();

$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT cb_skipe FROM #__comprofiler WHERE id= '{$risultato}'; ";
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadResult();
return $result; 
$mysqli->kill($db);
} 
}
?>
```

Comment: Where did you get this from `$result->fetch_object()->memTotal`? And what is this `$mysqli->kill($db);` Please refer to the Joomla documentation for database queries.

Comment: @lodder thanks, I used $ result-> fetch_object () returned an error because if not returned an error like he wants a "object or  string" i don't remember now i cheek, $mysqli->kill($db); these for "kill" but I've added later I'm not sure at all, now i study the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
<?php

class modUno {

    public static function due() {

        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select($db->quoteName('userid') . 'AS' . $db->quoteName('memTotal'))
              ->from($db->quoteName('#__session'))
              ->order('RAND()')
              ->setLimit(1);
        $db->setQuery($query);
        return $db->loadResult();

    }
    public static function tre() {

        $risultato = due();     
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select($db->quoteName('avatar'))
              ->from($db->quoteName('#__comprofiler'))
              ->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' = ' . $db->quote($risultato));
        $db->setQuery($query);
        return $db->loadResult();

    } 
    public static function quattro() {

        $risultato = due();     
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select($db->quoteName('cb_skipe'))
              ->from($db->quoteName('#__comprofiler'))
              ->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' = ' . $db->quote($risultato));
        $db->setQuery($query);
        return $db->loadResult();

    } 

}
?>
```

I have made some modifications however have not tested it so please let me know if it works or not.

Comment: blank page, now i study the Joomla documentation for database queries tanks anyway

Comment: @user3319781 - oops, I made a mistake. Try again now.

Comment: now retur these error : 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'RAND()' at line 3 SQL=SELECT `userid`AS`memTotal` FROM `some_session` ORDER BY ordering RAND()

Comment: @user3319781 - Updated the code, please try again now

Comment: uploaded but now blank page

Comment: tanks fro the time spent, for now i'v solved drop $mysqli->kill($db); and simplifying the function because I no longer need to check the result then I removed MemTotal these are the clean version, more later I try again on the sister site